# How to float more buttons on the left side

Tags: html, css

I am making a calculator and I have some basic buttons. I have other buttons written out, and I'm trying to put them on the left side.

I tried to float #extras to the left, but nothing happened.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ouybkvec/1/

Html:

```
<title>Calculator</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="calculator">
      <div id="total">
      </div>
      <div id="operators">
        <a>+</a>
        <a>-</a>
        <a>&divide;</a>
        <a>&times;</a>
      </div>
      <div id="side">
        <a id="sq">^</a>
        <a id="sqrt">√</a>
        <a id="decimal">.</a>
        <a id="equals">=</a>
      </div>
      <div id="numbers">
        <a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a>3</a>
        <a>4</a>
        <a>5</a>
        <a>6</a>
        <a>7</a>
        <a>8</a>
        <a>9</a>
        <a id="clear">C</a>
        <a>0</a>
        <a id="clearall">AC</a>
      </div>
      <div id="extras">
        <a id="factorial">x!</a>
        <a id="oneover">1/x</a>
        <a id="sine">sin</a>
        <a id="cosine">cos</a>
        <a id="tangent">tan</a>
      </div>
      </div>
        </body>
```

CSS:

```
body,
div,
a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Oswald, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/9YZkD5U.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
#calculator {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
  width: 370px;
  height: 465px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
#calculator a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

#numbers,
#operators {
  margin: auto;
}

#operators a {
  width: 46px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  color: #444;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

#numbers a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#total {
  height: 70px;
  width: 290px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #81A4B8;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 47px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

#side {
  width: 49px;
  float: right;
}

#side a {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

a#equals {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #d88d61;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#clear, #clearall {
  background-color: #f27b7b !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
#extras {
  float: left;
}
#extras a {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You have given a specific height for the whole div.

Comment: what's it supposed to look like?

Comment: Where should the extra buttons go? should it be inside the container?

Comment: The buttons should be inside the container next to the buttons on the right.

Comment: Here is my desired output: http://i.cubeupload.com/ZhZIUt.png

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class='test'>
  <div style='float: left;'>
    <button>test</button>
  </div>
  <div style='float: left;'>
    <button>test</button>
  </div>
    <div style='float: left;'>
    <button>test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test {
  width:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin:0px auto;
  border:1px red solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="calculator">
      <div id="total">
      </div>
      <div id="operators">
        <a>+</a>
        <a>-</a>
        <a>&divide;</a>
        <a>&times;</a>
      </div>
      <div id="side">
        <a id="sq">^</a>
        <a id="sqrt">√</a>
        <a id="decimal">.</a>
        <a id="equals">=</a>
      </div>
      <div id="numbers">
        <a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a>3</a>
        <a>4</a>
        <a>5</a>
        <a>6</a>
        <a>7</a>
        <a>8</a>
        <a>9</a>
        <a id="clear">C</a>
        <a>0</a>
        <a id="clearall">AC</a>
      </div>
      <div id="extras">
        <a id="factorial">x!</a>
        <a id="oneover">1/x</a>
        <a id="sine">sin</a>
        <a id="cosine">cos</a>
        <a id="tangent">tan</a>
      </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
```

css-->

```
.clear {
clear :both;
}
```

Remove height from .calculator css and you are good to go.

Comment: add this #calculator {
width: 316px;}

Comment: I wanted it to go to the left side.

Comment: which div should go to left?

Comment: extras should go left

Comment: Is this what you want?

Comment: Cant access that link - file not found.

Answer (score 0):

Put `side` `numbers` and `extras` under one div. Giving `width:100%` to their parent div and `10-to extras, 80-to numbers and 10-to side`

```
<div class='main'>
  <div id='extras'>
    <button>extras</button>
  </div>
  <div id='numbers'>
    <button>numbers</button>
  </div>
    <div id='side'>
    <button>side</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.main{
  width:100%;
}
#extras{
  width:10%;
}
#numbers{
  width:80%;
}
#side{
  width:10%;
}
```

Comment: could you provide me with a fiddle with this?

Comment: Try to implement it and i will help you correcting it :)

Comment: This is what it should look like: